# Vanilla javascript - insertRule CSS not working

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have 3 inputs which are colour pickers.

```
<input type="color" name="seconds-hand" value="#0c82cc" />
<input type="color" name="minutes-hand" value="#0c82cc" />
<input type="color" name="hours-hand" value="#0c82cc" />
```

Ive then written some javascript to find each one of these and update the styles in the header:

```
const input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const sheets = document.styleSheets;
const sheet = document.styleSheets[0];

function handleUpdate(){
    const element = document.getElementsByClassName(this.name);
    sheet.insertRule(`.${this.name} { background-color: ${this.value} }`);
    console.log(`.${this.name} { background-color: ${this.value} }`);
}
input.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate));
input.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemovement', handleUpdate));
```

The console log is returning the correct style to add to the style sheet, but nothing is being added. Am i using the incorrect js **.inserRule** ? I cant figure out why it isn't changing.

Any help would be great.

Comment: are you encapsulating that js to make sure the DOM is loaded before the JS is?

put the JavaScript in (function(){ ... })() and try again

Comment: Added the anon function to make sure DOM is loaded and still not working :(

Comment: It seems to be working fine, rules are added to the stylesheet, check the object in console here https://jsfiddle.net/zsz2xxej/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements you were trying to find weren't in the DOM when the script ran.
To fix this you can execute the code on [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event or [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) (document ready )

```js
window.onload = function(){
const input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const sheets = document.styleSheets;
const sheet = document.styleSheets[0];

function handleUpdate(){
    const element = document.getElementsByClassName(this.name);
    sheet.insertRule(`.${this.name} { background-color: ${this.value} }`);
    console.log(`.${this.name} { background-color: ${this.value} }`);
}
input.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate));
input.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemovement', handleUpdate));
}
```

```html
<input type="color" class="seconds-hand" name="seconds-hand" value="#0c82cc" />
<input type="color" class="minutes-hand" name="minutes-hand" value="#0c82cc" />
<input type="color" class="hours-hand" name="hours-hand" value="#0c82cc" />
```

Comment: another fix :  you could add the class same as the name to view live the changes <input type="color" class="seconds-hand" name="seconds-hand" value="#0c82cc" />